# Can sites get by with just mp4 video these days? Converting to other formats bloats the size

Tags: html, html5, video

Is it important to convert mp4 video to another formats like webm or is mp4 enough?

I tried to convert to webm in online services, but it makes the size of the video file much bigger. The size before was 7 MB and after it was converted it became 12MB.

```
<video controls>
    <source
        src="video.webm"
        type="video/webm"
    >
    <source
        src="video.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
    >
</video>
```

I want small page sizes, good performance, good quality, and browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content

Firstly,

> The audio and video tracks within the container hold data in the
>   appropriate format for the codec used to encode that media. Different
>   formats are used for audio tracks versus video tracks. Each audio
>   track is encoded using an audio codec, while video tracks are encoded
>   using (as you probably have guessed) a video codec.

Since MDN uses mp4 in demo, I don't see any contraindications.
For better compression you may use Cloudinary or Sirv or any dedicated video CDN.